# Cómo extraigo los números (de una lista) que sean mayores al número que yo indique?

Tags: python, lista, input, iteradores

Por ejemplo, si yo tengo la lista

lista=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

Y quiero los números mayores a 20, (esto lo indica el usuario), me tendría que devolver:

nuevalista=[30, 40, 50]

Es una pregunta tonta, pero estoy empezando en esto y no se a quién preguntar :(

El código que yo hice es el siguiente:

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]    
nueva=[]     
n=int(input("Introduzca un número entero"))    
def creador(v, l, n):    
  v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  l=[]    
  n=int(input("Introduzca un número entero"))    
  for item in v:    
      if item>n:    
          l.append(item)    
          return(l)    
  print(l)    

total=creador(lista, nueva, n)    
print(total)
```

Comment: el problema es que retorna la lista en la primera coincidencia, pon ese `return l` en el lugar del `print(l)`. También puedes hacer `return [num for num in v if num>n]`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

La función recibe varios valores que luego se redefinen dentro:

```
def creador(v, l, n):    
  v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  l=[]    
  n=int(input("Introduzca un número entero"))
```

A la función se le envían solo las variables que va a necesitar y retornará un valor (o valores).

```
def creador(lista_de_numeros, numero):
    ...
    # Crear una nueva lista con condiciones que pide el ejercicio
    ...
    return nueva_lista
```

Aquí la función recibe una lista de números y devuelve una nueva.

Fuera de la función (`main()`) se cargan los valores de la lista y se pide el valor del número

```
def creador(lista_de_numeros, numero):
    lista = []
    for item in lista_de_numeros: # recorrer lista
        if item > numero:
            lista.append(item) # añadir valores
    return(lista) # Al acabar de recorrer la lista devolver el resultado


lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
num = int(input("Introduzca un número entero"))

nueva_lista = creador(lista, num)
print(nueva_lista)
```

Como apunta @Christian en el comentario puedes utilizar la *comprensión de listas* y la función quedaría:

```
def creador(lista_de_numeros, numero):
    return [x for x in lista_de_numeros if x > numero]
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Al usar python tienes que tener mucho cuidado con indentar tu código de forma correcta ya que python lo utiliza para marcar el final de las declaraciones como en el caso de `if` o `for`

El `return(l)` que está dentro del `if` hace que termine el `for` al encontrar el primer valor mayor al número que indica el usuario

Para lograr que el `for` termine de iterar todo el arreglo y devolver el nuevo arreglo con números mayores al ingresado por el usuario debes indentar `return(l)` al mismo nivel que el `for`

También veo que estas solicitando dos veces al usuario ingresar el número entero, la línea `n=int(input("Introduzca un número entero: "))` dentro del def podría ser eliminada ya que n está declarada afuera de la función y es utilizada en total `total=creador(lista, nueva, n)`

Así quedaría tu código con las correcciones

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]    
nueva=[]     
n=int(input("Introduzca un número entero: "))    
def creador(v, l, n):    
    v=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    l=[]    

    for item in v:    
        if item>n:    
            l.append(item)
        
    return(l)    

total=creador(lista, nueva, n)    
print(total)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!1